# How do I Update Table with a Query from another Table Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to query Update Table A with Quantities from Table B:

```
WHERE
    [Table A].[Item Number] = [Table B].[Item Number] 
    AND [Table A].[ID] = [Table B].[ID]
```

Table A:

```
| Item Number | ID |Description | Unit Price | Quantity to Date |
+-------------+----+------------+------------+------------------+
| 5           |  b |            | $12.00     |                  |
| 1           |  a |            | $12.00     |                  |
| 2           |  b |            | $3.00      |                  |
| 3           |  a |            | $5.00      |                  |
```

Table B:

```
| Item Number | ID | Reported Quantity |
+-------------+----+-------------------+
| 1           | a  | 10                | 
| 2           | b  | 20                |
| 3           | a  | 10                | 
| 9           | c  | 232               |
```

I have tried:

```
UPDATE Table A
SET [Table A].[Quantity to Date] = (SELECT [Table B].[Reported Quantity] 
                                    FROM [Table A] 
                                    INNER JOIN [Table B] ON [Table A].[Item Number] = [Table B].[Item Number] 
                                                         AND [Table A].[ID] = [Table B].[ID])
```

I want it to look like this when it is combined:

```
| Item Number | ID |Description | Unit Price | Quantity to Date |
+-------------+----+------------+------------+------------------+
| 5           |  b |            | $12.00     |                  |
| 1           |  a |            | $12.00     |         10       |
| 2           |  b |            | $3.00      |         20       |
| 3           |  a |            | $5.00      |         10       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access SQL, you can simply update the INNER JOIN. Try creating the query in the query editor, and you will get something like

```
UPDATE [Table A ]
  INNER JOIN [Table B] 
    ON  ([Table A].[Item Number] = [Table B].[Item Number]) 
    AND ([Table A].[ID] = [Table B].[ID])
SET [Table A].[Quantity to Date] = [Table B].[Reported Quantity]
```

It's really straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery.  You don't need a `JOIN` in the subquery, just a correlation clause:

```
UPDATE [Table A]
    SET [Table A].[Quantity to Date] =
        (SELECT [Table B].[Reported Quantity] 
         FROM [Table B] 
         WHERE [Table A].[Item Number] = [Table B].[Item Number] AND
               [Table A].[ID] = [Table B].[ID]
        );
```

Note:  This assumes that there is only one matching row in `B` for each row in `A`.